# Adding Custom HTML Attribute To CF Wheels Forms

Tags: cfwheels

I'm trying to add a VueJS HTML Attribute

> v-show = "someName"

inside a generated textField form input in CFWheels. By default, CfWheels doesn't allow hyphens.

For HTML5 attribute that starts with "data", this is possible

```
#linkTo(text="Home", route="root", dataDomCache=true)#
-> <a href="/" data-dom-cache>Home</a>
```

However, I would like to get the same functionality using v-show instead of data-com-cache.

Anyone knows a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would likely need to use the argumentCollection:

```
<cfset vueArgs = { "v-model"="foo" }>
#linkTo(text="Home", route="root", dataDomCache=true, argumentCollection=vueArgs)#
```

You could try something like this also, but I'm not sure if it'll work:

```
#linkTo(text="Home", route="root", dataDomCache=true, "v-model"="foo")#
```

Comment: Wow, you're the same guy in the CFWheels Google Group page. Not sure why your answer isn't documented in cfwheels website, but this trick did it. Thanks!